# asp.NET Core timed BackgroundService cannot be stopped in Controller with StopAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service

I have implemented a REST API Server with asp.NET Core. I need a background task which does some administrative stuff.

I tried the several suggestions in the web to create a timed background task and implemented it as fpllowing:
BackgroundService.cs

```
public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private Task _executingTask;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);

    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

        if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return _executingTask;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_executingTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            _stoppingCts.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));
        }

    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        _stoppingCts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

RecureHostedService.cs

```
public class RecureHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private int _executionCount = 0;
    private Timer _timer;

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref _executionCount);

            log.InfoFormat(
                "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {0}", count);
            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

SystemController.cs

```
public class SystemController : Controller
{
    private readonly RecureHostedService _recureHostedService;

    public SystemController(IHostedService hostedService)
    {
        _recureHostedService = hostedService as RecureHostedService;
    }
    [HttpGet(ApiRoutes.System.Start)]
    public IActionResult Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start Service");
        _recureHostedService.StartAsync(new CancellationToken());
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet(ApiRoutes.System.Stop)]
    public IActionResult Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stop Service");
        Console.WriteLine(_recureHostedService == null);
        _recureHostedService.StopAsync(new CancellationToken());
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

in Startup.cs I added the Service as Singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService,RecureHostedService>();
```

The RecureHostedService starts on startup of my app and does its work. When I do an APIrequest /api/v1/stop from the SystemController (method Stop()) I got an NullReferenceException in

```
_recureHostedService.StopAsync(new CancellationToken());
```

I found out that the private member variable _recureHostedService is null even if I had assigned it in the Constructor of the SystemController. So it seems that the Service Injection of _recureHostedService is not working. So the line

```
_recureHostedService = hostedService as RecureHostedService;
```

in the Constructor of SystemController assigns null to _recureHostedService. 
How can that be? I've a lot of other Services injected to other Controllers and all works fine.
Any idea from anyone, why it is not working with that Hosted Service?

Best 
Mic

Comment: As far as I know, you shouldn't really call `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` on background tasks. Let the framework do that. You just register it with `AddHostedService`, the rest is done for you.

Comment: For this special recurring service, I need a way to pause and resume it depending on other states. So I thought using those public methods would do it. Several examples relate to it and suggest to use them.

Answer (score 2):

I used a set of static variables for myself

```
public class RecureHostedService : BackgroundService {
    public static bool isPause = false;
/* for example
    public static string ErrorText;
    public static bool isError = false;
    public static bool isWorked = false;
    public static bool firstStart = true; */

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken){
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), stoppingToken);
         if (isPause)
            continue;
         var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref _executionCount);
         log.InfoFormat(
            "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {0}", count);
         await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
    }
    }
}

public class SystemController : Controller 
{

[HttpGet(ApiRoutes.System.Start)]
public IActionResult Start()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start Service");
    RecureHostedService.isPause = false;
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet(ApiRoutes.System.Stop)]
public IActionResult Stop()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stop Service");
    RecureHostedService.isPause = true;
    return Ok();
}
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah. This works very fine. It's more a pause than a start and stop. But perhaps this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register you hosted service using `AddHostedService` instedad of `AddSingleton`
so it will be something like this

```
services.AddHostedService<IHostedService,RecureHostedService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you perfer inject **IHostedService** on constructor, keep `_recureHostedService` property declared as type of **IHostedService**, instead of the concrete class ***RecureHostedService***. It's not necessary down-casting here.

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SystemController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostedService _recureHostedService;

    public SystemController(IHostedService hostedService)
    {
        _recureHostedService = hostedService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hostedService));
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

I've tested this controller, no null exception any longer in either this way

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, RecureHostedService>();
```

or

```cs
services.AddHostedService(p =>
{
    return new RecureHostedService();
});
```

Comment: Trying your suggestion removes the NPE but the Service does not stop when accessing the endpoint action for Stop(). Acessing the Controller endpoint a secord time creates a "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Using dependency injection to obtain an IHostedService will inject whichever hosted service was defined first. Which is likely to be the web server itself. Instead you should define two service definitions that return the same singleton;

```cs
services.AddSingleton<RecureHostedService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(p => p.GetRequiredService<RecureHostedService>());

public class SystemController : Controller
{
    private readonly RecureHostedService _recureHostedService;

    public SystemController(RecureHostedService hostedService)
    {
        _recureHostedService = hostedService;
    }
}
```